# How to apply a special methods 'Mixin' to a typing.NamedTuple

Tags: python, python-3.6, namedtuple

I love the `typing.NamedTuple` in Python 3.6. But there's often the case where the `namedtuple` contains a non-hashable attribute and I want to use it as a `dict` key or `set` member. If it makes sense that a `namedtuple` class uses object identity (`id()` for `__eq__` and `__hash__`) then adding those methods to the class works fine.

However, I now have this pattern in my code in several places and I want to get rid of the boilerplate `__eq__` and `__hash__` method definitions. I know `namedtuple`'s are not regular classes and I haven't been able to figure out how to get this working.

Here's what I've tried:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class ObjectIdentityMixin:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self is other

    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self)

class TestMixinFirst(ObjectIdentityMixin, NamedTuple):
    a: int

print(TestMixinFirst(1) == TestMixinFirst(1))  # Prints True, so not using my __eq__

class TestMixinSecond(NamedTuple, ObjectIdentityMixin):
    b: int

print(TestMixinSecond(2) == TestMixinSecond(2))  # Prints True as well

class ObjectIdentityNamedTuple(NamedTuple):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self is other

    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self)

class TestSuperclass(ObjectIdentityNamedTuple):
    c: int

TestSuperclass(3)    
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    TestSuperclass(3)
TypeError: __new__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
"""
```

Is there a way I don't have to repeat these methods in each `NamedTuple` that I need 'object identity' in?

Comment: How is the__init__() method of your class ObjectIdentityNamedTupl?

Comment: @DamianLattenero I've edited my question to show a full code example. There is no `__init__`. I've tried adding `__new__` but `NamedTuple`s don't allow that.

Comment: It looks like PEP 557 coming in Python 3.7 might solve all of this.

Comment: You can used Dataclasses here in Python 3.7_.  It behaves like `NamedTuple`, and it allows you to override `__eq__`.  Just decorate the class with `dataclasses.dataclass`.

Comment: Documentation references for Dataclasses: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The magic source of `NamedTuple` class syntax is its [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) `NamedTupleMeta`, [behind the scene](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/typing.py#L2131), `NamedTupleMeta.__new__` creates a new class for you, instead of a typical one, but a class created by `collections.namedtuple()`.

The problem is, when `NamedTupleMeta` creating new class object, it ignored bases classes, you could check the MRO of `TestMixinFirst`, there is no `ObjectIdentityMixin`:

```
>>> print(TestMixinFirst.mro())
[<class '__main__.TestMixinFirst'>, <class 'tuple'>, <class 'object'>]
```

you have to extend `NamedTupleMeta` to take care of base classes:

```
import typing


class NamedTupleMetaEx(typing.NamedTupleMeta):

    def __new__(cls, typename, bases, ns):
        cls_obj = super().__new__(cls, typename+'_nm_base', bases, ns)
        bases = bases + (cls_obj,)
        return type(typename, bases, {})


class TestMixin(ObjectIdentityMixin, metaclass=NamedTupleMetaEx):
    a: int
    b: int = 10


t1 = TestMixin(1, 2)
t2 = TestMixin(1, 2)
t3 = TestMixin(1)

assert hash(t1) != hash(t2)
assert not (t1 == t2)
assert t3.b == 10
```

Comment: Great work. I was about to mark this answer correct but then came across a really subtle and damn confusing bug in it. If one of the fields has a default value then the value TestMixin is initialized with is used everywhere except when accessing the field by name. In your example, if you change the declaration of `b` to: `b: int = 0` then:
`str(t1)` returns `TestMixin(a=1, b=2)`: correct;
`t1[1]` returns 2: correct;
`t.b` returns `0`: fail.

Comment: @DamonMaria interesting, will look into it later.

Comment: @DamonMaria check updated code, `ns` has already attached to the base class created by `namedtuple()`, should not be overridden.

Comment: Thanks @georgexsh, just tried it and now all my tests are passing. Thank you.

Comment: @DamonMaria very glad that I helped, in fact, I have spent many hours on this.

Comment: FYI: this doesn't work in Python 3.9: the first line in `NamedTupleMeta.__new__` now has an assert statement that the first base class is a `_NamedTuple`